# AsyncStorage returning JSON Parse error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage

I have a simple app - code at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/KidzGaming/Trail-Mobile). In the `App.js` file, I use a method called `Backend.getUser()`, which simply gets the The `user` object from `AsyncStorage` as a string. So, if the object exists, the user should be taken to the Home screen without waiting at the login screen. If not, the login screen is displayed. This can be seen [in this file](https://github.com/KidzGaming/Trail-Mobile/blob/master/App.js).

The problem is, instead of doing this, I get a warning in the console; and the app remains on the login screen, even if the `user` object exists.

The warning:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Tholle, the project i a bit too big for that. The question will become verbose

Comment: It's very unlikely that people will help you unless you supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your getUser function By below code

```
getUser(){
  return AsyncStorage.getItem('@Trail:user').then((itemValue)=>{
    return  itemValue
  })
}
```